# Bash shell: Count occurrences of pattern (in one file) listed in arrays (array elements loaded from different file)

Tags: bash, unix

Hi I have loaded patterns of pattern.txt file into array and now I would like to grep count of each array element from second file (named as count.csv)

**pattern.txt**

```
abc
def
ghi
```

**count.csv**

```
1234,abc,joseph
5678,ramson,abc
2231,sam,def
1123,abc,richard
2521,ghi,albert
7371,jackson,def
```

bash shell script is given below:

```
declare -a myArray

myArray=( $(awk '{print $1}' ./pattern.txt))

for ((i=0; i < ${#myArray[*]}; i++))    
do    
   var1=$(grep -c "${myArray[i]}" count.csv)    
   echo $var1    
done
```

But, when I run the script, **instead of giving below output**

```
3
2
1
```

**It gives output as**

```
0
0
1
```

i.e. it only gives *correct count of last array element.*

Answer (score 3):

***grep*** + ***sort*** + ***uniq*** pipeline solution:

```
grep -o -w -f pattern.txt count.csv | sort | uniq -c
```

The output:

```
  3 abc
  2 def
  1 ghi
```

---

*grep* options:

- `-f` - obtain pattern(s) from file
- `-o` - print only the matched parts of matching lines
- `-w` - select only those lines containing matches that form whole words

---

The alternative ***awk*** approach:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{p[$0]; next}{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i in p) {p[$i]++; break} }}
     END {for(i in p) print p[i],i}' pattern.txt FS="," count.csv
```

The output:

```
2 def
3 abc
1 ghi
```

---

- `p[$0]` - accumulating patterns from the 1st input file (`pattern.txt`)
- `for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)` - iterating though the fields of the line of the 2nd file (`count.csv`)
- `if($i in p) {p[$i]++; break}` - incrementing counter for each matched pattern

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest #     grep -o -f pattern.txt count.csv | sort | uniq -c
          1 abc
          1 def
          1 ghi

Comment: @laxmansharma, check again - it works fine for your input. Otherwise, you have posted nonactual input. Besides, it should  be executed as one 
independent  line, without any loop

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use `awk` for processing text files line by line:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR {wrd[$1]; next} $2 in wrd{wrd[$2]++} $3 in wrd{wrd[$3]++} 
END{for (w in wrd) print w, wrd[w]}' pattern.txt count.csv

def 2
abc 3
ghi 1
```

**Reference:** [Effective AWK Programming](https://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf)

Comment: It gives output: ef, ghi and bc

Comment: You probably have DOS line ending in your files. Run `dos2unix` on both files before you run this `awk` command.

Comment: If `dos2unix` is unavailable then `awk -v RS='\r\n' -F, 'NR==FNR {wrd[$1]; next} $2 in wrd{wrd[$2]++} $3 in wrd{wrd[$3]++} END{for (w in wrd) print w, wrd[w]}' pattern.txt count.csv` will also work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this command instead:

```
mapfile -t myArray < pattern.txt
for pattern in ${myArray[*]}; do
  echo $(grep -o $pattern count.csv| wc -l)
done

Output:
3
2
1
```

`mapfile` will store every pattern in pattern.txt into `myArray`
The `for` loop will iterate through each pattern in `myArray` and print the number of occurrence of `pattern` in count.csv

Comment: It gives output '0'

Comment: i m getting strange output. It gives count value of **abc** as 1 but when i put all the field **abc** of 3 rows in third column (pattern.txt file), it gives correct output.

Comment: @laxmansharma Not quite sure what you mean, but it works for both cases where your patterns are on one line (`abc def ghi`) or on separate lines like in your example pattern.txt

Answer (score 0):

You could also skip the array and just loop over the patterns:

```
while read -r pattern; do
    [[ -n $pattern ]] && grep -c "$pattern" count.csv
done < pattern.txt
```

`grep -c` outputs just the counts of the matches

Comment: It is not giving count value of third pattern (ghi)--only count of abc and def i m getting. Further, i m getting strange output. It gives count value of abc as 1 but when i put all the field abc of 3 rows in third column (pattern.txt file), it gives correct output.